# Testing for Inactivity in Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos

Is there a way to test, using Python, how long the system has been idle on Mac? Or, failing that, even *if* the system is currently idle?

**Answer**

Using the information from the accepted solution, here is an ugly but functional and fairly efficient function for the job:

```
from subprocess import *

def idleTime():
    '''Return idle time in seconds'''

    # Get the output from 
    # ioreg -c IOHIDSystem
    s = Popen(["ioreg", "-c", "IOHIDSystem"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    lines = s.split('\n')

    raw_line = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line.find('HIDIdleTime') > 0:
            raw_line = line
            break

    nano_seconds = long(raw_line.split('=')[-1])
    seconds = nano_seconds/10**9
    return seconds
```

Comment: What does "idle" mean?  How do you define it?

Comment: Whatever the system defines as "idle". I.e. what the system considers idle time before enacting the Screensaver or Energy Saver. I'm assuming no mouse or keyboard movement would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. I tried to use it with python 3, and had to make the following changes. Before the split, added a line s=s.decode("utf-8"). And instead of long(raw_line.split('=')[-1]), had to use int(raw_line.split('=')[-1]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested (for now), but [according to this thread](http://www.dssw.co.uk/sleepcentre/threads/system_idle_time_how_to_retrieve.html) you could parse the output of

> ioreg -c IOHIDSystem

Comment: Okay that works. Posting my solution in the original question. Thanks for the lead.